# How to find the value of tangent vectors?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry, vector-analysis

[image]

In the figure $z_1=a_1+ib_1$ and $z_2=a_2+ib_2$ are the two curves. $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the tangents on the curves $z_1$ and $z_2$. What I am interested to know what will be the tangent vectors?

Comment: Are these curves differentiable?

Comment: Yes, these curves are differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent vectors will be:
$$\frac{dz_1}{dt}=\frac{da_1}{dt}+\frac{dib_1}{dt}=\frac{da_1}{dt}+0 \cdot b_1 +i\frac{db_1}{dt}=\frac{da_1}{dt} +i\frac{db_1}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dz_2}{dt}=\frac{da_2}{dt}+\frac{dib_2}{dt}=\frac{da_2}{dt}+0\cdot b_2 +i\frac{db_2}{dt}=\frac{da_2}{dt} +i\frac{db_2}{dt}$$
Is this what you were looking for?

Since $(a'_1,b'_1) \cdot (a'_2,b'_2)=|(a'_1,b'_1)||(a'_2,b'_2)|\cos{\alpha}$:
$$\alpha=\cos^{-1}(\frac{(a'_1,b'_1) \cdot (a'_2,b'_2)}{|(a'_1,b'_1)||(a'_2,b'_2)|})$$
Given $(a'_1,b'_1),(a'_2,b'_2) \neq (0,0)$

Comment: why $0.b_1$ and $0.b_2$ ?

Comment: I was using the product rule for differentiation: $\frac{dib}{dt}=\frac{di}{dt}b+i\frac{db}{dt} = 0 \cdot b + i\frac{db}{dt}$

Comment: What you think if I'll write $z'_1(t)$ and $z'_2(t)$ as the tangent vectors of the curves?

Comment: Should be fine I think

Comment: If $\alpha$ is the angle between $T_1$ and $T_2$, what you think about it if I write it as, $cos \alpha = \frac{z'_1(t_1) . z'_2(t_2)}{|z'_1(t_1)||z'_2(t_2)|}$? Am I write or not?

Comment: Yes, but remember that you need to treat the space as $\mathbb{R}^2$ with basis $\{1,i\}$. i.e, "disregard" $i$